# Is it possible to verify someone else's smart contract on Etherscan?

Tags: tokens, etherscan, mint, contract-verification, burn

I just deployed an ERC20 token on the Rinkeby testnet. The token has some features like Minting and Burning. After verifying the code on Etherscan I am able to interact with the functions and generate more tokens or burn them as I am supposed to.

However I just realized that whoever has access to the .sol file which contains the smart contract could potentially verify the ERC20 token itself, thus being able to mint or burn instead of me.

[image]

Is this even possible? If not, what am I missing in my logic?

Comment: Of course it is possible. Take a look at [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol), it might help you.

Comment: @Pail thanks for the comment! How are then ERC20 tokens protected from this? Is there some workaround? I found out that there is a onlyOwner() modifier. Is placing this in the function definition enough to prevent what I described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is right. Anybody with the source code can verify any contract.

For example, I deployed this contract:

`0xD93f610B9b70E9aCda192091645F48ACfB63C676`

with this account: `0x6827b8f6cc60497d9bf5210d602C0EcaFDF7C405`

And then I made sure that my Metamask was not connected to etherscan and used incognito, and I was able to verify it:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract-solc?a=0xd93f610b9b70e9acda192091645f48acfb63c676&c=v0.8.16%2bcommit.07a7930e&lictype=3

Comment: thanks for the answer! How are then ERC20 tokens protected from this? Is there some workaround? I found out that there is a onlyOwner() modifier. Is placing this in the function definition enough to prevent what I described?

Comment: If only you want to be the minter, yes, you can use `onlyOwner`. If you want specific addresses to be able to mint, then you should add access control logic, like `mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted` or something like that.

Comment: Awesome that is good news. I was pretty scared cuz I thought anyone could mint instead of me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they could.  And in fact if the contract has been deployed before (same bytecode), many explorers are automatically verifying it.  But the big thing you should know is that **people can interact with your contract even if it's not verified**.  You should have access controls built into the smart contract, meaning only certain addresses can do the minting or burning.

Comment: thanks for the answer! How are then ERC20 tokens protected from this? Is there some workaround? I found out that there is a onlyOwner() modifier. Is placing this in the function definition enough to prevent what I described?

Comment: yup! That's the way to do it.

Comment: @FedericoGentile If you want it so only your account can mint and burn tokens, you need to write that in the contract: if someone else tries to mint or burn tokens it won't work. Obviously one way to do that is with onlyOwner.

Answer (score 1):

Verification has nothing to do with minting or burning.

Only the compiled form of the contract is deployed on the blockchain. Not the source code.

Verification means that someone uploads a copy of the source code to (in this case) Etherscan, then Etherscan compiles it to make sure it's actually the same code, and if it matches, it gets displayed on Etherscan. This is all to do with the Etherscan website, totally unrelated to the actual blockchain.

Until someone puts the source code on Etherscan, Etherscan has no idea how to call the contract properly. That's probably why you thought verification had something to do with calling. But anyone who could work out the correct way to call the contract (by looking at the compiled code) could have called it before.

If you want to make it so only a certain person can burn or mint tokens, you need to write that into the contract. One way to do that is with onlyOwner, as other people have said.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!!